# Listbox selecteditem problem wpf

Tags: wpf, listbox, selecteditem, dataview

I am binding dataview to listbox. How to get the selected item.

Geetha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the reply. I got the solution.

Code:

```
  DataRowView dv = lbResult.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
   string xx= dv.Row[1].ToString();
```

Geetha.

Answer (score 0):

By the property `YourListBox.SelectedItem.ToString()`

Comment: Not sure why you ToString() the result.

Comment: This just returns "System.Data.DataRowView"